# Can I switch a Google Play country without adding payment method?

Tags: google-play-services

Here's the deal.
I need to check if our Platform supports payments over 1000000 currency via Google Play Store.

When I try to change the country in Account settings, Google asks for that country's payment method (Credit card). I don't have access to Vietnamese test cards and the ones from card generator don't work (obviously). Any ideas on how I can skip adding a payment method? The account is used only for Sandbox testing purposes.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD88MJNwwTRo94/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/play/8MJNwwTRo94 maybe this helps

Comment: Thank you! That indeed helped. I had to create another Payment user through payments.google.com with fake Vietnamese card. The user got created, but without payment card. Which is enough for me, cause I was able to make test payments with new Vietnamese Payment User.

Comment: Posted it as an answer for future Users with the same Question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD88MJNwwTRo94/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/play/8MJNwwTRo94) Page from the Google Play Support Page if you encounter a similar Problem.

> Also, you can't change the country for an existing payments profile. Hence, you need to create a new payments profile to add/associate it with a new/another country:
>
> 1. Sign in to [Settings](http://payments.google.com/#settings).
> 2. Under **Payments profile**, click the pencil icon next to **Country**.
> 3. Click the link to **Create new profile** from the message that appears.
> 4. Click **Continue** from the next message that appears.
> 5. From the drop-down list, choose the country to associate with the payments profile you're creating.
> 6. Enter the address information and click **Submit**.
>
> After that you'll be seeing an option "Close" at the bottom part of the selection where you need to close the payments account under your previous location.`

Comment: The ONLY answer that really works after spending days if not weeks finding a solution to this problem.

Comment: It is 2021 and this is still the ONLY answer I got that works. Upvoted.

Comment: The linked page for payments settings profile no longer has a pencil icon or the word "country" anywhere on it. The only button says "Add a payment method".

Comment: Don't be evil my a*s. As @craq mentioned at some point they have changed this and now the only thing you can do is "Add a payment method".
What worked for me was to just add dummy info. It doesn't even have to be a real card, as long as validation passes you will be able to proceed to the steps described here.